# Searching all tables in database containing specific column

Tags: sql, ssms, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking for a simple query to find all tables within a database that have a certain "id" column,  confusing myself as not all the tables contain this "id"

Comment: SQL Server (SSMS is not a RDMS just a client UI to SQL Server) or Snowflake? Pretty sure it can't be both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/columns.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'id'
```

Comment: Good grief way too simple..  take breaks from your code once in a while people youll confuse yourself for no reason on the dumbest of things,  ill leave this up tho for others.  Thanks Lukasz!!!